# how to get edge weight and node-node with DFS traversal

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a digraph built using NetworkX and need to print *Node-Node-EdgeWeight* details as I make a **DFS** traversal of the graph with every node as source.

I have success in getting the *node-node* details as I traverse, but also need edge-attributes as I traverse.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge("A", "B", weight=1)
G.add_edge("B", "C", weight=2)
G.add_edge("B", "D", weight=3)
G.add_edge("D", "E", weight=4)
G.add_edge("B", "E", weight=5)
G.add_edge("A", "E", weight=6)

for node in G.nodes:
    print(list(nx.dfs_tree(G, source=node)))

for node in G.nodes:
    print(list(nx.dfs_edges(G, source=node)))
```

---

Expected Output:

[('A', 'B', ***1***), ('B', 'C', ***2***), ('B', 'D', ***3***), ('D', 'E', ***4***)]

[('B', 'C', ***2*** ), ('B', 'D', ***3***), ('D', 'E', ***4***)]

....

---

Actual Output:

[('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('D', 'E')]

[('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('D', 'E')]

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [get_edge_data](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.MultiDiGraph.get_edge_data.html) on G to access the weight. For example,

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge("A", "B", weight=1)
G.add_edge("B", "C", weight=2)
G.add_edge("B", "D", weight=3)
G.add_edge("D", "E", weight=4)
G.add_edge("B", "E", weight=5)
G.add_edge("A", "E", weight=6)

for node in G.nodes:
     for edge in list(nx.dfs_edges(G, source=node)):
         print edge[0], edge[1], G.get_edge_data(edge[0],edge[1])['weight']
```

The output is:

```
A B 1
B C 2
B E 5
B D 3
B C 2
B E 5
B D 3
D E 4
```